# Subtract from values in a dataframe by condition

Tags: r

I want to select some columns from my dataframe, and subtract a number from all values meeting a condition. In my case, i want to select columns 5:10 of my data, and subtract 10 from all values >5, while keeping all other values the same, and then saving this dataframe.

The solution i have tried (below) just subtracts 10 from all the values. How can I do this? Any help much appreciated.

```
data <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(-1:10,1000,rep=TRUE)))    #generate random data


# what i have tried so far
(data[, 5:10] > 5) - 10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in base r you may use lapply

```
lapply(data[, 5:10], function(x) ifelse(x > 5, x - 10, x))
```

---

In dplyr you can do

```
data <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(-1:10,1000,rep=TRUE))) 
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

data %>%
  mutate(across(5:10, ~ifelse(.>5, . - 10, .)))

    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1    9  3  3  5 -2 -4  1  4 -4  -1
2    1  0  7  7 -2  3  2 -1  4  -3
3    2 -1  8  1  1  1 -4  0  0   3
4    9  9  4  6 -2 -3  3  0  0   0
5    7 -1  9  5  0  1  1 -1 -1   2
6    4  9  4  7  4  1  0 -1 -3  -1
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use -

```
cols <- 5:10
data[cols] <- data[cols] - 10 * +(data[cols] > 5)
```

`+(data[cols] > 5)` would give you 1/0 values which is multiplied by 10. So you'll have 10 for values which are greater than 5 and 0 otherwise. These values are subtracted from the selected columns of the dataframe.

Comment: nice hack with the `*+(logical)`. +1. This is probably very efficient too.

Answer (score 0):

I would use dplyr and base subsetting here.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% mutate(across(5:10, ~{.x[.x>5]<-.x[.x>5]-10; .x}))
```

We can also substitute the whole subsetted dataframe in place, without loops or lapply, which can be done with not-so-beautiful but potentially very fast code:

```
data[,5:10][data[,5:10]>5]<-data[,5:10][data[,5:10]>5]-10
```

**output**

```
    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1    8 -1  0  3  1 -1 -2  0  1  -1
2    5  6  5  4  4  4 -1  3  2  -3
3   10  4  4  4  4  0 -3 -3  4  -1
4    1  7  5  5 -2  0 -3  5  1   5
5    0  6  7  1  0 -3  0 -1 -1   3
6    8  4  7  4 -3  5  0 -4  1   2
7   -1  5  9  7  0  1  0  2  4   4
8    9  8  5  3 -1  5 -3 -1 -4  -1
9    9  9  8  8  4  2  1 -1  1   3
10   8  8  9  5  2 -4  2 -3 -3  -1
......
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 900 rows ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `vapply()`:

```
colIndices <- seq(5, 10)
df[,colIndices] <- vapply(
  df[,colIndices],
  function(x){
    ifelse(x > 5, x - 10, x)
  },
  numeric(nrow(df))
)
```